# Convert Multiple SWF files to Single EXE

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, adobe

Hi I have an application in flash, I build in `ActionScript 3.0` Flash IDE, my application loads some external swfs which mentioned via XML file. Its working fine at the moment. But I need to compile all these external `SWFs` and `xml` file into single **`exe`** file. `How can I compile like this`. or `how can I code like this`?

**EDIT: 1**
from here : http://page-flip.com/products/pdf-publisher/

You can see an example, the application is build in .net and it import pdf and publish it as flash projector or web based(swf). How is it compiling all the external SWF files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you have Flash CS4 you can make use of the mxmlc compiler which has some additional tricks up it's sleeve.

Using the embed tag like this will allow you to embed an entire swf "inside" your swf:

```
[Embed(source = '../assets/items/9.swf')] public static const ITEM_9:Class;
```

Then, to instantiate it you simply go:

```
var mySprite:Sprite = new ITEM_9() as Sprite;
```

Using this and some clever overloading of your current classes for external loading should allow you to get a single swf ([xml files can be embedded in a similar fashion](http://dispatchevent.org/roger/embed-almost-anything-in-your-swf/)).

Then it's just a matter of using the Publish settings to make Flash spit out an .exe

On an unrelated note, please go back and accept some answers to your questions. It's not very nice not to.

Answer (score 2):

You can try [mdm Zinc](http://www.multidmedia.com/software/zinc/).

Zinc is really powerful. It lets you package your Flash or Flex in different ways, with lots of native platform hooks.

Answer (score 0):

you can build an AIR application.  if you don`t want it to be cross platform, you can build an AIR application with a windows native installer.

Comment: No I don't want AIR, I need the Flash EXE file.

Comment: what's a Flash EXE file?  are you talking about an AIR application with a windows native installer?

Comment: No, I'm not talking about AIR, I need Flash EXE(Publish)

Comment: The OP is looking for a "Flash Projector".

Answer (score 0):

Flash > File > Project settings > Windows Projector.

For MAC, choose a MAC projector.

If you are burning to a disc and you need both platforms to work...a good option is to use Toast (if you are on a MAC)...it will hide the files you don't need the user to see, and also hide windows files from MACs and vice versa.

Comment: +1... "publish settings".  this is certainly the official way for sure.

Comment: Sure it's official, but it doesn't answer the question!

Comment: From my personal experience, Flash compiles multiple .swf files into a single .exe or .app (Mac projector) file...that's why the .app/.exe files are so much larger than individual .swf files. But it's true, I don't know exactly *how* it compiles these multiple .swf files together.

Answer (score 0):

There is an application for Windows called SWFKit, which allows you to package your SWF and external files into one exe file. I had the same problem as you, and this worked a treat for me. Unfortunately you do need to pay for it :( http://www.swfkit.com

Hope this helps,
Will

Answer (score 0):

I would go about it with these steps

1. create a flex application
2. embed all of the SWF's and the XML into that application
3. create a release of the application you just created
4. open the SWF application with the stand-alone flash player and not with the browser
5. from the file menu select the option create projector

All of this will result a single EXE file that contains all of the SWF's and the XML file.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a projector or make an windows only AIR project.

Answer (score 0):

Use flajector and forget about your problems